# Mule: Deployment Error reading plugins

Tags: mule, mule-studio

While deploying simple hello world application on Mule, i am getting following error. Any way to resolve the same?

```
Reading plugins from: D:/MULE/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.0_3.5.0.201405141856/mule/plugins
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Version: Mule Studio 3.5, 
Java: JDK 1.6

Flow include a HTTP adapter|Request-Response and logger only.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue.

Actually, I was creating project with Mule Cloud Runtime; but I need to create it with Mule Server 3.4.1 EE. After creating project correctly, i am able to deploy it successfully.